# Is this form of distribution considered Bimodal or Uniform?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

[image: Distribution Example]

Would this form of distribution be considered Bimodal or Uniform? I have been searching through distribution images and the Bimodal distributions generally appear to refer to a pair of Normal distributions not a pair of Uniform distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bimodal is a term for when there are multiple maxima in a pdf. Here, your function is monotonic, hence it has only one mode at the far left. It is also not uniform.

I would call it a "piecewise uniform" distribution.